# Does this graph operation have a name? Subgraph join?

Tags: graph-theory, binary-operations

Given a graph $G$ and two of its subgraphs $A$ and $B$ we define another subgraph, $A+B\subseteq G$ as the subgraph with the following properties,

- The vertex set of $A+B$ is the union of the vertex sets of $A$ and $B$
- The edge set of $A+B$ is the union of the edge sets of $A$ and $B$ but also includes any edges joining $A$ and $B$ that are also edges in $G$, i.e. if a $a\in V(A)$ and $b\in V(B)$ then $\{a,b\}$ is an edge of $A+B$ if and only if $\{a,b\}$ is an edge in $G$.

Does this operation on subgraphs have a name? In the case where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint subgraphs of $K_n$ then this would be equivalent to the graph join, hence my first guess for a name would be the subgraph join.

Comment: How is $A+B$ different to the subgraph induced by $A \cup B$?

Comment: In the second bullet I specify that the edge set is in general not just the union of the edge sets of A and B. For example if I have the the square $C_4$ and A,B,C,D are the subgraphs corresponding to each of the four vertices in clockwise order, then $A+B$ has 1 edge but $A+C=A\cup C$ and so has no edges.

Comment: Yep, I get you now. Sorry, I was thinking of $A$ and $B$ as sets. For the record, I wouldn't call this the subgraph join, since the subgraphs of $G$ form a lattice $\mathrm{Sub}(G)$, and the lattice-theoretic join in $\mathrm{Sub}(G)$ is just the familiar graph-theoretic union.

Comment: The motivation behind naming it a "subgraph join" was that the definition is similar to that of a graph join (second definition at this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_operations#Binary_operations), nevertheless what you said is a good point I'll keep in mind.